# Node - Prevent child process from going in to parent directory

Tags: node.js, directory, cd, child-process

I am spawning a process from my node server, that is in `/tmp/running/username` (it is a node process uploaded by the user)

how do I prevent it from reading (or knowing of the existence of) anything other than `/tmp/running/username`?

I can spawn the process in any required way.

Comment: Which operating system? Linux?

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson Unix Or Linux, Not Windows.

Comment: Perhaps spawn the process using `chroot`? `spawn('chroot', ['/tmp/running/username', 'yourprocess', 'arg1', ...])` (or use [node-posix](https://github.com/melor/node-posix#posixchrootpath)).

Comment: Does the user need the full power of node.js? Could you just spawn a VM for the user? http://nodejs.org/api/vm.html  You can pass them just the things they need.

Comment: @robertklep: please put that in an answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could spawn the process as an argument for `chroot`, which will change the root directory for your process:

```
spawn('chroot', ['/tmp/running/username', 'yourprocess', 'arg1', ...]);
```

An alternative would be to use the `chroot` function from the [node-posix](https://github.com/melor/node-posix#posixchrootpath) module (but to prevent the Node process from which you spawn your external program from being chrooted as well, you may need to fork first and call chroot from the child process).